# Problems with actionbar and searchview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm using actionBar and searchView, and this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {

    super.onCreate(savedBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    setupImageLoader();
    setupSlidingMenu();

}

....

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and my menu file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Now what I see is this:

[image]
[image]

When not selected the SearchView is on the bottom of the screen, and it becames part of the actionbar only when active. How can I embed it like in Play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your java-code, it seems that you are using FragmentActivity and thus the android-support library. But your selected SearchView-class is from the native Android framework.

Look at the developer-docs to see how it should be done:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Also, it seems you have the splitActionbar enabled, or else your search-button would appear in the upper actionbar. So check your AndroidManifest.xml for something like this:

```
<activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```